# Whatsapp on domain joined computer

Tags: windows-10, installation, whatsapp

I'm trying to install WhatsApp application on a domain joined Windows 10 PC. I must enter administrator password to install the application but the source file was installed into Administrator profile.

Every time the non-admin user tries to open WhatsApp, the computer asks for Administrator password. I can't give the administrator password to the user.

I want WhatsApp to be installed in C:\Program Files. But the installer doesn't give an option to choose the installation path.

This problem also applies to Viber Desktop and Slack. How can I solve this?

Comment: The non-admin user is logged in when I install the application. After I enter the admin password, the installer loads without any button or fields. Viber Desktop has the same problem.

Comment: have you tried installing them from the store?

Comment: yes...I installed from Store and it was fine. Thanks.

Comment: But how about Slack and Viber Desktop?

Comment: I'm sure Viber is also available from the store? Have you checked slack?

Answer (score 0):

Apps can be installed without admin rights from Microsoft store.

All three apps you mentioned are available from there, try installing from the store.